# About the parameter of Landau theory

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition

I had seen that the Landau free energy below:

F=$F_0+\frac{1}{2}aP^2+\frac{1}{4}bP^4+\frac{1}{6}cP^6+...-EP$

I would like to ask why *a* is temperature dependent but b and c are temperature independent. And I also want to ask if I want to find out the information about the critical region which theory I can use because Landau theory fails in the critical region.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: on "Electrocaloric Effect: Theory, Measurements, and Applications"

Answer (score 1):

The Landau theory was meant to be a theory of the critical regime (This is needed to truncate the expansion in $P$). In general all coefficients are functions of $T$, but $a$ changes sign near the critical point $a(t)=ct+\ldots$ whereas $b$ and the other coefficients are finite, $b(t)=b_0+\ldots$.

We now know that the Landau theory (in its simplest form) is not correct. Landau thought that the free energy functional can be used in the mean field approximation, but very close to $T_c$ fluctuations invalidate the mean field treatment, and the full machinery of statistical field theory and the renormalization group is required.